# .removeData not removing data id

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that shows a dialog box to confirm if an item should be deleted. The problem is, every time I click the delete button, the id of the item is added to #dialog data every time.

So the first time I delete, it alerts just the id like I'd expect. If I click another item to delete, it shows the previous id as well. How can I clear the data attached to dialog properly?

```
// Delete confirmation modals
$('#dialog').on('show', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.data('id');

    $('#delete-confirm').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

        $this.removeData('id', id);

        alert(id);

    });
});

$('.delete').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#dialog').data('id', $(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: Did you try `$this.removeData('id')` instead of `$this.removeData('id', id)`? `removeData()` only takes one argument.

Comment: There isn't an error, the problem is how I described in the question. It keeps adding the id to the data when I only need it once.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ya, I just tried it again as well. Same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never updating the `id` variable to the new value of `.data('id')`

```
// Delete confirmation modals
$('#delete-confirm').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $("#dialog").removeData('id');    
    alert($("#dialog").data('id'));    
});

$('.delete').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#dialog').data('id', $(this).data('id'));
});
```

Also, make sure you aren't binding multiple events to the same element, which could happen with the `delete-confirm` element. Confirm by making the dialog appear multiple times, and confirming the delete multiple times. if the alert starts happening more and more times, then you are re-binding the event.

Comment: Ya, the dialog box is appearing multiple times. Any ideas on how to prevent it from doing this?